# I ran ganache-cli and it returned an error. i've reinstall npm and nothing done

Tags: node.js, npm, truffle, ganache

I ran ganache-cli and it returned an error. I've reinstalled npm and nothing happened.

> C:\Users\Abass KABORE\Desktop\Stage_DISCOM\BSCcrowdsale>ganache-cli
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Abass
> KABORE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\dist\node\cli.js'
> ←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m ←[90m    at
> Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
> ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m ←[90m    at
> node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {   code:
> ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,   requireStack: [] }
>
> Node.js v17.3.1

Answer (score 1):

type

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

into to the terminal. Ganache has rolled out a new update that fixed previous bugs.

Answer (score -1):

type

```
npm install -g ganache-cli --force
```